# Searching for a particular string in 5000+ text files.

Tags: java, c++, file, search

I solve bugs for a product. The customer has sent a bundle of log files. I am required to search for a particular string in these log files. The number of log files is more than five thousand.

**I cannot use grep because I am working on a windows machine.**

What are my options here ? I was thinking about writing a program in java where I open every text file in a directory and search for a particular pattern. But I could not find a api where i can open every file one after the other.

Can you please suggest me a solution. I can also code in C++ or C# is somehow a solution can be built there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perl. It takes about three lines of code to search every file in a directory for a string. You can learn enough Perl to do that in half an hour.

Comment: I think that @Ritwik is more concerned about perfomance that about time for programming

Comment: @BlackBada - my point was that if someone isn't familiar with Perl, it's still easy to get this going.

Answer (score 13):

I would suggest installing Cygwin and using grep

Comment: and instead of monstrous cygwin, IMO, msys would be a better solution

Comment: @DenisTulskiy What's wrong with cygwin ? I never had any problems with it.

Comment: there's nothing wrong with the way cygwin works, it's just that cygwin is, like, more than a gig of disk space and is basically an os within os. while msys is lightweight and easy to install.

Comment: I disagree, it might be a big package, but it's far from an OS within an OS, as clearly stated on their website

Answer (score 5):

If you need to do this only manually, then just install any decent editor (my suggestion would be http://notepad-plus-plus.org/), and use its find-in-files function.

Comment: so you suggest I do a ctrl+A and then open in Notepad++ ?

Answer (score 2):

How about using findstr command from command prompt.

Answer (score 1):

This works in Windows XP.  I don't know about the more current versions.

Click on the Windows Start Button
Click on Search
A new window will open.  On the bottom left, click on "Click here to use Windows Search Companion"
Another window will open.
In the text box labeled "A word or phrase in the file" type in what you're looking for.
In the combobox labeled "Look in", at the very bottom, select "browse..." and select the folder with all the log files.
Click "Search"
Wait for the results...

Note: there are 2 search programs.  The first one only finds things that have been indexed, which is why you should use the second search program instead.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Consider [VIM editor](http://www.vim.org/download.php) which is awesome when working with huge files. You can use it under Cygwin, and you can use on Windows. Use [cheat sheets](http://www.viemu.com/a_vi_vim_graphical_cheat_sheet_tutorial.html) to learn it quickly.